Move some items in part of an animation
I'm creating an animation of a logistic system with objects moving through several steps. Now we want to change the layout of the system, so to adjust the animation I need to change the x and y location of some (many) objects on some parts of the timeline.
My hunch would be to use the graph editor to change the x and y coordinates separately for all relevant objects and keyframes together.
Is there a way to filter the graph editor so you see and edit only e.g. the x coordinates of all selected objects. I know you can lock and hide the other coordinates but that requires a lot of clicking.
Other methods than using the graph editor are also welcome.
